# Configuring sink data set in azure data factory

Tags: copy, dataset, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy multiple folders with their files (.dat and .csv ) from ftp to Azure storage account , so I am using a get metadata for each and copy activity. My problem is that when setting the file path in the output data set I am not sure how to set the filename so it picks up all files in my folder.

I added a filename parameter in the data set and in the copydata sink I set it as @item().name but it's not working instead of copying the files, it copies the folder. the second try is that I dont set the filename in the directory, and it does copy the files but it adds the extension.txt to the files instead of keeping their original format.

Thank you for your help,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDWGu.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIQwc.png)

Comment: Hi, I just worked on this today! Can you post picture of Sink tab of copy activity? and related dataset?

Comment: I have added pictures , do you have any recommendations on how to solve this .

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a third parameter for the sink dataset for filename.

Here you can pass parameter as you have for container and folder.
Filename can be set from the Get Metadata activity output.

Comment: How ? when I set filename as @activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems It returns the error : ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidValueInPayload,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to convert the value in 'fileName' property to 'System.String' type